# Matlab writematrix in Excel gives error: Name cannot be the same as built-in name

Tags: excel, matlab

I want to copy an Excel file to a different path through Matlab and then write in it also using Matlab. Somehow I get the error: Name cannot be the same as built-in name.
As I want to write multiple times in the file, I don't want to solve this problem manuelly each time, I want the code to run through without me having to do something constantly.
Is there any way I can solve this problem all at once through code? Does this happen because I copy the Excel file first?

The code looks like this:

```
path_source_template1 = 'Blabla1\Template1.xlsx';

timestamp = datestr(now);
timestamp = strrep(timestamp, ':', '-');
timestamp = strrep(timestamp, ' ', '-');

path_output = fullfile('Blabla2\',timestamp);
mkdir(fullfile(path_output));

path_output_template1 = strcat(path_output,'\Template1.xlsx');

copyfile(path_source_template1,path_output_template1);
```

Then I want to write in the Template1.xlsx:

```
writematrix(test,path_output_template1,'Sheet','Test','Range','A1',UseExcel=true,AutoFitWidth=false);
```

Then I get this error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/99bhl.png)

Comment: What name? Are you defining a name for the matrix or table? Or are you just leaving it to default? Show more detail of what name gives the error.

Answer (score 0):

The input to the `writematrix` file uses the `name, value` format, so in this line:

```
writematrix(test,path_output_template1,'Sheet','Test','Range','A1',UseExcel=true,AutoFitWidth=false);
```

you should have:

```
..., 'Sheet','Test','Range','A1','UseExcel', true,'AutoFitWidth', false);
```

Disclaimer: I haven't tested this, but I'm fairly certain this will fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The correct call to the writematrix would be:

```
writematrix(test,path_output_template1, 'Sheet','Test','Range','A1', 'UseExcel', true,'AutoFitWidth',false);
```

When writing datetime data to a spreadsheet file, you must set both 'PreserveFormat' and the 'UseExcel' Name-Value pair to true to preserve the existing cell formatting. You can check the documentation [writematrix](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/writematrix.html).

In order to answer to the error I tested the code locally in Matlab 2019b and works well setting the test variable in this example way: `test = magic(5);`.

Maybe the error could be in the data that you use in test variable or in that if you run the code iteratively very fast the `path_output` could exist, One way to improve this could be with a more accurate `timestamp`.